# Brownian Bridge equivalence of definitions

Tags: probability-theory

How can I verify the equality of the distributions arising from the two definitions of Brownian Bridge here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge

The two definitions are $W_t-tW_1$ and $(W_t|W_1=0)$.  The meaning of the latter is interpreted through singular conditioning, meaning that since all densities involved are continuous, for $0<t_1<\dots<t_n<1, A_1, \dots, A_n$ Borel, the definition of $P(W_{t_i}\in  A_i \forall i: 1\le i \le n|W_1=0)$ is the limit $P(W_{t_i}\in  A_i \forall i: 1\le i \le n|W_1 \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon))$.  I assert that this limit exists as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, and moreover that the set function so defined forms a probability measure defining all the finite dimensional distributions.  They are kolmogorov consistent, so one can extend to all of $\mathbb{R}^{[0, 1]}$.  This probability measure is the distribution of $(W_t|W_1=0)$ and I wish to see that this probability measure is also the (joint as $t$ varies) distribution of $W_t-tW_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $t \in [0,1]$,

We have $W_t = W_t - tW_1 + tW_1$ and $cov(W_t - tW_1, W_1) = t - t = 0$. Since they are jointly Gaussian, we get $W_t - tW_1$ and $W_1$ are independent.

So $(W_t |W_1 = 0) = (W_t - tW_1 + tW_1 | W_1 = 0) = W_t - tW_1 + (tW_1 | W_1 = 0) = W_t - tW_1$.

Similarly, we can get the identity for vector $(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$

\begin{align}
E(f(W_{t_1},\cdots, W_{t_n}) | W_1 = 0) &= E(f(W_{t_1}-t_1W_1 + t_1W_1,\cdots, W_{t_n}-t_nW_1 + t_n W_1) | W_1 = 0)\\
& =  E(f(W_{t_1}-t_1W_1,\cdots, W_{t_n}-t_nW_1))
\end{align}

where I used if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(f(X,Y)|X=x) = E(f(x,Y))$

Comment: Actually my trouble is getting the multivariate distributions.  It does not seem like they are amenable to this sort of argument.  Does one proceed instead by showing that relative to $P(.|W_1=0)$ the vector $W_{t_i}$ is a multivariate Gaussian, and then try to compute the covariances?  I'm not sure how this, or some other strategy, would proceed.

Comment: @Jeff I added several lines